# Bluetooth Problem in Linux Mint 18.2

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, xfce, bluetooth, usb-device

I am running Linux Mint 18.2 (64-bit, Xfce) on a Dell Latitude D430. It runs fine, but bluetooth does not appear to be working. I can detect devices, but connecting doesn't always work, and sending files always fails. I've tried switching out my bluetooth device to a USB dongle, and even booted into Linux Mint MATE and Black Lab Linux (which uses a different USB client). The problem persists under all circumstances. I have no such problem on my other computer, running Mint Cinnamon on a Dell Studio 1737. Can anyone tell me if this is a Ubuntu driver bug, or if I am looking at a more serious hardware issue? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to U&L . Please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/399766/edit) by adding the output of `rfkill list` and `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

In most of all cases it works.

Comment: Thanks! I also just discovered that by removing my device from the list of known devices and re-pairing it seems to solve the problem as well. For some reason it didn't work yesterday, worked today.

Comment: I've traced the problem back to the particular bluetooth card installed in my computer. Unfortunately, it does not appear to support a connection with an old Nokia C3. Thanks for the tip, though!